# Using Nodejs to perform image manipulations async and cannot understand promises or callbacks to determine when all manipulations are done

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I apologize for asking a question that has been posted many times already but I cannot understand how to adapt the examples/solutions/tutorials to my code. I am constrained by modifying someone else's code and cannot start from scratch.

I am using nodejs v6.10 and async code processing is difficult to implement for me despite reading many articles and wikis.

I am trying to determine exactly when all the operations are complete and I believe promises are the right way for me. I cannot figure out how to get it to work correctly, but I am not getting any warnings or errors anymore.

I think my biggest problem is that my image manipulation functions don't return anything and I'm trying to force them to without success.

here is my basic code:

```
var finished;
main();

function main() {
    do stuff...
    fs.readFile(JSON,...) { 
        finished = theApp(JSON);
});

Promise.all(finished).then(function(x, y) {
    var total = x * y;
    console.log("completed: " + total + " at " + Date.now());
        }).catch(function() {
            console.log("failed.");
        });
}

function theApp(JSON) {
    do stuff...
    for $loop (1..100) {
        do JSON stuff...
        resizeImages(JSONparameters, image);
    }

    for $loop2 (1..100) {
        do JSON stuff...
        finished = function() {
            return manipulateImages(JSONparameters, image);
        }
    }
}

function resizeImages(JSONparameters, image) {
    do stuff...
    for $i (1..100) {
        sharp(image)
            .resize(x, y)
            .toFile(output)
    }
}

function manipulateImages(JSONparameters, image) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        do stuff...
        for $i (1..100) {
            sharp(image)
                .blur()
                .toFile(output)
        }
    });
}
```

I realize it's a lot of loops, but this is the architecture that is my constraint for now. I also realize that I only put the promise at the manipulateImage step. This is because the resize operation completes before the manipulateImages operation starts.

In this configuration, the manipulateImages function is called many times, but nothing is output. If I strip out the "return new Promise" wrapper around the code, it works fine. But then I don't know how to return anything that can be passed back to main to wait until the promises.all() returns resolved.

Can someone please educate me on how to allow me to console.log the exact time when all the operations are complete? Thank you.

Comment: Your manupulate images function returns a promise, but then in your loops you are just setting the finished variable to a function that returns said manipulate images function. I dont see where you are calling anything. You could instead add the result of calling the manupilate images function to an array and then after all the loops are run, call Promise.all() with the array of promises and in its success function, that would be when all the promises have returned.

Comment: There are lots of issues with your "architecture". You're using `finished` when it's not yet assigned to. You're using the return value of `theApp` when there is none. You are assigning to `finished` in two different places. `Promise.all` expects an array, but you're (in one case) assigning a single Promise to `finished`. You are creating a Promise, but you are never resolving or rejecting it. You're probably using a Promise while using functions that are probably not async...

Comment: If you are using Promise.all make sure the variable finished is of type array and has promises inside it. Thats the only thing I see off the top of my head with your code. Right now it looks like finished is a function and not an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: What language is `for $loop (1..100)`?

Comment: Your understanding of promises appears to be very misguided and is not correct in pretty much any place you are attempting to use them.  As such, it's not a few simple corrections to make your code work.  Instead, you probably have to describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish in words and then we can better help you figure out what code would be appropriate for that problem.

Comment: @Ken "add the [promises] result of calling the manipulate images function to an array" would this operation be in loop2 of theApp function? "call Promise.all() with the array of promises and in its success function" would that be something like Promise.all($manipulateImagesPromisesArray).then(function success() {...

Comment: @jfriend00 from the description: "I am trying to determine exactly when all the operations are complete and I believe promises are the right way for me. I cannot figure out how to get it to work correctly, but I am not getting any warnings or errors anymore."

Answer (score 3):

I think your basic understanding of Promises is not quite there and that your solution is complicated enough that it's making it even more difficult for you to understand the core of what Promises are and how they work. Think about it like this:

```
// List of images
let images = [
  'image1.jpg',
  'image2.jpg',
  'image3.jpg',
]

// Array to store promises
let promises = []

// Loop through your images
for (const image of images) {

  // Create a new promise, adding it to the array
  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Do your resizing, manipulation, etc
    sharp(image)
      .resize()
      .blur()
      .toFile(output, function(err, data) {  // Assuming this toFile is an async operation and uses a callback

        // After all the resizing, manipulation and file saving async functions are complete, resolve the Promise
        resolve()
      })


  })
}

// Wait until all promises in the promises array are resolved
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((){
    console.log('image resizing and manipulation is complete')
  })
```

The best way to understand a Promise is that, within your Promise, you do all your async stuff. Deal with callbacks, etc. Do whatever you need to do asynchronously in the Promise. When you are done, `resolve` it. That is what signals that the Promise is complete.

The `Promise.all` is waiting for all the Promises in the promises array to finish before it run's it's `.then()` method.